# Rust Lifetime on HashMap

Tags: rust

How do you add lifetime on the HashMap when inserting a key?

I have this setup on my struct and have been getting this error:

```
// ! ERROR: a value of type `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, u64>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `(&str, {integer})`
```

so I did this. I added a lifetime to my struct.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
  pub struct LInstruction<'a> {
    pub label: HashMap<&'a str, u64>
  }

impl<'a> LInstruction<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> LInstruction<'a> {
       LInstruction {
        label: [
          ("R0",      0),
          ("R1",      1),
          ("R2",      2),
          ("R3",      3),
          ("R4",      4),
          ("R5",      5),
          ("R6",      6),
          ("R7",      7),
          ("R8",      8),
          ("R9",      9),
          ("R10",     10),
          ("R11",     11),
          ("R23",     12),
          ("R13",     13),
          ("R14",     14),
          ("R15",     15),
          ("SP",      0),
          ("LCL",     1),
          ("ARG",     2),
          ("THIS",    3),
          ("THAT",    4),
          ("SCREEN",  16384),
          ("KBD",     24576)
        ].iter().cloned().collect()
      }
    }
  }
```

but then, when I created this method for my struct.

```rust
 pub fn add_labeler(&self, tokens: Vec<&str>) {
      let mut counter = 0;
      for token in tokens {
        if token.starts_with("(") && token.ends_with(")") {
          let label_name = token.trim_start_matches("(").trim_end_matches(")");
          &self.label.insert(label_name, counter);
        }
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
```

I got this error:

[image]

the `label_name` is having some lifetime issue. I don't know where to put the lifetime in the label_name variable because `trim_start and trim_end` returns a `&str` (string slice).

So my current solution, for now, is to remove the lifetime, Change the HashMap key type to `String` then do this to the initial value, but then it'll be cumbersome to add the `.to_string()` method to each string slice.

```rust
[
 ("R0".to_string(),      0),
 ("R1".to_string(),      1),
 ("R2".to_string(),      2),
 ("R3".to_string(),      3),
 ...
]
```

This is my 3rd day learning Rust so I'm not familiar with lifetimes.

Comment: This is one area of rust that I wish was easier. I am following this question and looking forward to answers from people who understand it better than I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the declaration of `LInstruction`, you specify a lifetime `'a` of the `&str` references stored inside the `label` `HashMap` field. In the struct's `impl`, you call this lifetime `'a` (using the syntax `impl<'a> LInstruction<'a>`). To put it simply, this implies that each `&str` reference stored in the `label` `HashMap` field of every `self` instance has a lifetime of `'a`. In other words, when you try and insert a `&str` key into `self.label` (as you do in `add_labeler`), the reference you add must also have a lifetime of `'a`.

In `add_labeler`, you are attempting to add the `label_name` to `self.label` as a key. Since `label_name = token.trim_start_matches("(").trim_end_matches(")")`, `label_name` is a slice of the same `String` that `token` is a slice of. Because both slices point to data from the same source, they have the same lifetime. As `token` is an element of `tokens`, its lifetime is specified in the `tokens` parameter signature.

Due to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html), the lifetime of the `&str` references in `token` is *different* than the lifetime of `&self`. The unelided signature would be `fn add_labeler<'b>(&self, tokens: Vec<&'b str>)` -- recall that the `&str` references in `self.label` (and by extension `&self`) have a lifetime `'a` as defined in the `impl`. This is now a problem, as `token` would have a lifetime `'b`, which does not satisfy the lifetime requirement `'a` needed for it to be safely added to `self.label`. The solution to this is to specify that the references in `tokens` must indeed have the same lifetime as the references stored in `self.label`, by explicitly adding the `'a` lifetime to its type (`tokens: Vec<&'a str>`).

The compiler error tells you exactly where to put the lifetime as well:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `tokens`
  --> src/lib.rs:46:35
   |
41 |     pub fn add_labeler(&self, tokens: Vec<&str>) {
   |                                       --------- help: add explicit lifetime `'a` to the type of `tokens`: `Vec<&'a str>`
...
46 |                 self.label.insert(label_name, counter);
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'a` required
```

Note that in order to get `add_labeler` to compile, you will also have to borrow `self` as mutable with `&mut self` as you are modifying the `self.label` field in the function body.

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate the help. I have another question. I was randomly adding lifetime to the method and it removed the error. I added it like this. `tokens: &'a Vec<&str>` what's the difference between `tokens: &'a Vec<&str>` and `Vec<&'a str>`?

Comment: @aRtoo: There is a rule in Rust that says that a value cannot live longer than its type: when you write `&'a Vec<&str>`. Since your vector must live for `'a`, so do the values inside, and the nameless lifetime of `&str` also satisfies `'a`.